# Mozilla firefox redirecting websites to greefl

Tags: firefox

I am having problems with firefox lately. When I try to access some websites, i.e. foxsports, I get redirected to ww7.greefl.com. I checked my plug-ins but nothing looks suspicious - shockwave flash, divx web player, itunes application detector, quicktime plug-in, vlc multimedia plugin, windows media player plug-in.

I am not sure what's causing this and when I google "remove greefl", I get these strange looking websites in the search result.

I have tried refreshing firefox but the problem came back after 1 week.

How do I fix this? I am a bit desperate... Thanks!

Comment: Why is there an antivirus tag on this question?

Comment: You might want to try what the tag you chose says: antivirus. http://smallbusiness.chron.com/fix-browser-redirect-linux-80059.html

Comment: Has your 'Home' page been hijacked in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Many malwares can fake being a useful addon like flashplugin and what not. Here is such a report https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/953200. Even removing them won't remove the changes in settings.

I recommend resetting Firefox instead. To do so, follow these steps

1. Click the icon that looks like three stacked lines at the top right of the browser window.
2. Click on the question-mark icon at the bottom of the drop-down menu.
3. Click on 'Troubleshooting information' in the slide-out menu.
4. Click the 'Refresh Firefox' button at the top right of the new Web page.